# modify merge sort for storing original indexes

Tags: c, sorting, mergesort

I tried to modify merge sort for storing original indexes after modification it is not sorting properly.. I am not able to find where I have gone wrong Please help me find the issue..

Please find my code below.

```
void merge(int a[][2],int start,int middle ,int end)
{
    int size1 = middle-start +1;
    int size2 = end-middle;
    int i,j;
    int k =start;
    int L[size1][2];
    int R[size2][2];
    //int *L = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*size1);
    //int *R = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*size2);

    // copy values from main array to temp arrays
    for(i=0 ; i<size1; i++)
    {
        L[i][1] = a[i+start][1];
        L[i][0] = a[i+start][0];
    }
    for(j=0 ; j<size2 ; j++)
    {
        R[j][1] = a[j+middle+1][1];
        R[j][0] = a[j+middle+1][0];
    }

    i=0;
    j=0;
    while(i<size1 && j<size2)
    {
        if(L[i] < R[j])
        {
            a[k][1] = L[i][1];
            a[k][0] = L[i][0];
            k++;
            i++;
        }
        else{
            a[k][1] = R[j][1];
            a[k][0] = R[j][0];
            k++;
            j++;
        }
    }
    while(i<size1)
    {
        a[k][1] = L[i][1];
        a[k][0] = L[i][0];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while(j<size2)
    {
        a[k][1] = R[j][1];
        a[k][0] = R[j][0];
        k++;
        j++;
    }
}

void mergeSort(int a[][2], int start , int end)
{
    if(start < end)
    {
        int middle = start + (end - start) /2;
        mergeSort(a,start, middle);
        mergeSort(a,middle+1,end);
        merge(a,start,middle,end);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int array[10][2] = {{0,55},{1,3},{2,4},{3,5},{4,6},{5,7},{6,8},{7,9},{8,10},{9,2}};
    int i;
    int len = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]) - 1;
    for(i = 0 ;i <= 9; i++)
        printf("%d",array[i][1]);
    mergeSort(array,0,9);
    printf ( "\nArray after sorting:\n") ;
    printf ( "\nindex after sorting:\n") ;
    for(i = 0 ;i <= 9; i++)
        printf("%d",array[i][0]);
    printf ( "\nArray after sorting:\n") ;
    for(i = 0 ;i <= 9; i++)
        printf("%d",array[i][1]);
}
```

Comment: First indent your code, second your question is unclear explain that is problem. bug? logic?

Comment: who in the world teaches to use "uppercase - single Letter" Variable names like "L" and "R"?

Comment: i=>indexLeft, j=>indexRight, k=>indexResult, size1=>sizeLeft, size2=>sizeRight, L=>arrLeft

Comment: It would be considerably easier to simply sort the indexes (valuation based on `a[i]` for index `i`); not the actual sequence itself.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan i have added details, can you please check now.

Comment: @PeterMiehle i will keep this in mind.. thanks

Comment: @WhozCraig can you please explain it a little. That would be really helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: Note the first value in your original 2D array. its the natural index to the array itself. so *just sort an array of those*, using an unmodified `a[]` parameter to determine the "value" for comparison. When finished, you'll have an array of indices that presents the original unmodified array in sorted order, and the indices themselves are the original locations.

Comment: Thanks, i will try using this technique.. Can you please also see whats going wrong in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Your fundamental issue is in your initial while-loop of your merge algorithm:

```
if(L[i] < R[j])
```

this is comparing memory addresses of two int[2] arrays, not the values held in the second slot of said-same, which is what you should be doing.

```
if(L[i][1] < R[j][1])
```

That said, this could be made considerably simpler, but that is the crux of the main problem.

---

**Pointer Math Version**

To supplement the comment I dropped in this answer, the following is a reduced version of your code that uses pointer math for the segment splits rather than just indexes. Look carefully at the recursive calls to `mergeSort()` as well as the parameters. Also note the use of a single temp array and indexes in the `merge` algorithm:

```
void merge(int a[][2], int mid, int len)
{
    int tmp[len][2];
    int i,j,k=0;

    // copy values from main array to temp
    memcpy(tmp, a, len*sizeof(*a));

    i=0; j=mid;
    while(i<mid && j<len)
    {
        if (tmp[i][1] < tmp[j][1])
        {
            // take from left side
            a[k][1] = tmp[i][1];
            a[k][0] = tmp[i++][0];
        }
        else
        {   // take from right side
            a[k][1] = tmp[j][1];
            a[k][0] = tmp[j++][0];
        }

        ++k; // always incremented
    }

    // one of these is skipped. the other will
    //  finish the merge algorithm
    while(i<mid)
    {
        a[k][1] = tmp[i][1];
        a[k++][0] = tmp[i++][0];
    }

    while(j<len)
    {
        a[k][1] = tmp[j][1];
        a[k++][0] = tmp[j++][0];
    }
}

void mergeSort(int a[][2], int len)
{
    if (len > 1)
    {
        int mid = len / 2;
        mergeSort(a, mid);
        mergeSort(a+mid, len-mid); // note: pointer math for right-segment
        merge(a, mid, len);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int array[10][2] = {{0,55},{1,3},{2,4},{3,5},{4,6},{5,7},{6,8},{7,9},{8,10},{9,2}};
    int i;
    int len = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
    for(i = 0 ;i < len; i++)
        printf("%d ",array[i][1]);

    mergeSort(array, len);

    printf ( "\nIndex after sorting:\n") ;
    for(i = 0 ;i < len; i++)
        printf("%d ",array[i][0]);

    printf ( "\nArray after sorting:\n") ;
    for(i = 0 ;i < len; i++)
        printf("%d ",array[i][1]);
}
```

**Output**

```
55 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 2 
Index after sorting:
9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 0 
Array after sorting:
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 55
```

Comment: And now code is working! I tried.

Comment: Thanks a million WhozCraig. Yes I am now going to use other method suggested by you. Also greatly appreciate you finding out this issue.

Comment: @user3184719 No problem. You may also want to consider using pointer math and eliminating one of the parameters to both `merge` and `mergeSort`. it actually makes the algorithm easier as reduces a chance for using the wrong index (since you only have two, a `mid` and an `end`). Anyway, glad it helped.

Comment: @WhozCraig this makes it simpler thanks.. I tried to work out using approach mentioned  by you before, butcould not get it i.e "It would be considerably easier to simply sort the indexes (valuation based on a[i] for index i); not the actual sequence itself" Can you please provide code with explaination if its not much work for you. Or can point me to link where its already available. Thanks in advance